# Class Casting during Marshalling of JAXB

Tags: java, class, casting, jaxb, marshalling

**Objective**: trying to pass any class through the parameter `c` so any class could use marshaling directly.

**Error**: [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.Class" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]

This error was given at line pointed with the arrow(-->)

**Comments**: if i try to change `c` at the line 8 & 9 with an expression from an actual class then this works just fine. Is there any way without doing this. Class casting is no option I think.

```
public XmlMarshaller(Class c){
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(c);
        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        --> marshaller.marshal(c, new File("xmlDyna/asd.xml"));
        --> marshaller.marshal(c, System.out);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the other class in case anyone thinks the error is with the missing @XmlRootElement annotations.

```
@XmlRootElement( name = "Dynamic")
public class DynamicLoader {

@XmlElement(name = "name")
public String name = "asdasd";

public DynamicLoader(){
    XmlMarshaller marshaller = new XmlMarshaller(this.getClass());
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to marshal java.lang.Class in your xml?

Comment: i wasnt trying to marshal lang.Class object. I was trying to pass another object through (Class c) as a parameter. The problem is in the line with (-->) instead of c it must be the name of the class. What do you think i should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `Object` as a parameter instead of `Class`.  Then make sure you pass an instance of the class in instead of the class itself.  Then bootstrap the `JAXBContext` on `object.getClass()`.

Comment: I feel stupid :) ..anyway thanks for the answer Blaise. Although still getting the same error message at the same lines but the xml was created.

Answer (score 0):

The object which you are passing to be marshaled is missing annotations. 
@XmlRootElement is needed in order to define a root element. Likewise @XmlAttribute is used to identify xml attributes etc.